# How to convert bytes stream data to GTPv2 msg type using scapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I am working with scapy for some time, and I have a problem to convert bytes data to properly GTPv2-C msg with proper header and IE body.
I have prepared bytes type msg variable (contains proper GTPV2EchoRequest msg):

`echo_bytes_msg =b'H\x01\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\x00\x03\x00\xa99\x12'`

I know how to create the msg using GTPHeader class, IElist type object and combined it in one msg, but i don't know how to reverse this process.
I was trying to use GTPHeader class with one private method (_pkt):

```
from scapy.contrib.gtp_v2 import *    
echo_res_bin = b'H\x01\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\x00\x03\x00\xa99\x12'    
    Original_msg = GTPHeader(_pkt=echo_res_bin)
    Original_msg.show()
```

But return result are as fallow:

```
##[ GTP v2 Header ]### 
  version   = 2
  P         = 0
  T         = 1
  SPARE     = 0
  SPARE     = 0
  SPARE     = 0
  gtp_type  = echo_request
  length    = 15
  teid      = 0x0
  seq       = 0
  SPARE     = 0
###[ Raw ]### 
     load      = '\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\x00\x03\x00\xa99\x12'
```

The header itself is decode properly, but IE body elements are treated as Raw load. Do anyone can help me with this or have some idea how to handle those.
Th goal is to decode msg without knowing what msg is expected from the service for example

Using python ver: 3.8.3

Used scapy-lib ver: scapy===git-archive.devcb13a5fa19

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the scapy lib have some bug regarding the Echo Request and Response header msg definition. After fixing this, all GTPv2-c msg are decoded properly. The bug find in scapy.contrib.gtp_v2 lib:

```
bind_layers(GTPHeader, GTPV2EchoRequest, gtp_type=1, T=0)
bind_layers(GTPHeader, GTPV2EchoResponse, gtp_type=2, T=0)
```

Should be changed to:

```
bind_layers(GTPHeader, GTPV2EchoRequest, gtp_type=1) 
bind_layers(GTPHeader, GTPV2EchoResponse, gtp_type=2)
```

It seams that this T variables messed up i the IE length elements, and cause that GTPHeader function can properly decode msg.

Comment: you should report this bug to the devs so that they can fix it